Passing an array to a function in C - array subscript vs pointer dereferencing
Coming from mainly Python and JavaScript
I (think I) understand that when you pass the name of an array to a function, the array is decayed to a pointer. The part that confuses me is the fact that the pointer can be indexed using the array subscript operator.
Is the subscript operator just a shorthand for de-referencing and some pointer arithmetic?
#include <stdio.h>

void myFunc(int arr[]) {
    // arr is the pointer to the first element in the array

    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);     // prints 1
    printf("%d\n", *arr);       // prints 1
    printf("%d\n", arr[1]);     // prints 2
    printf("%d\n", *(arr + 1)); // prints 2
}

int main () {
    int myArr[] = {1,2,3};
    myFunc(myArr);
}

I did not expect to be able to use a array subscript operation on an int (pointer)

Is the subscript operator just a shorthand for de-referencing and some pointer arithmetic? yes

For any array or pointer a and index i, the expression a[i] is exactly equal to *(a + i) (I think this is explicitly mentioned in the C specification). And because of the commutative property of addition, *(a + i) is equal to *(i + a) which leads to the expression i[a] being valid and equal. Also, a[0] is equal to *(a + 0) which is equal to *(a) which is equal to *a.

The array subscript operator [] is always used with a pointer and an integer type.  When used on an array, the array is converted to a pointer before the operator is applied.  a[b] is defined as *(a+b).  Whenever it's used, you're adding a pointer and an integer.
